# Set CSS style properties using templates

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

I am using Flask with the default template engine, Jinja2.

So I have a bunch of products in my database and they each have a style column which contains information for how they should be rendered, i.e: accent colors, fonts, but when trying to use inline styles - I would like to do it that way it seems the most concise - I get no results. The template engine just seems to the ignore variable I insert...

```
... style="border-color:#{{ product.style.color }}">
```

I inspect the code from the browser's developer tools - both in Firefox and Chrome - and it seems that the variable hasn't been expanded at all by Jinja. I get the following if I view the code...

```
... style="border-color:#">
```

I have queried all the products and made sure that their style row's (for the products I am working with) are all valid.

So I am asking if there is a way to inline styles and dynamically set their properties using templates?

I am sorry in advance if this question has been solved. It's very specific and I couldn't manage to find and questions that struggled in this area. Feel free to point me to any external resources.

regards Keagan

Comment: Can you check the source file to see if there is actually something? sometimes css ignores invalid color references.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz I use python in cmd, to manage the database (I know right, I am sure there must be a better way) and I have copied values straight from the values in the database and when I hardcode them they work fine.

Comment: can you print `product.style.color` to check what is getting from the DB?

Comment: I have that's how I copied and pasted, but I wil give you an example.3EFF61
E27CE8
FF443B
415FE8
74FFF5 I'm fairly sure that all of these work

Comment: does that only happens on styles? I mean, if you put `{{ product.style.color }}` on a <p> does it print the color code?

Comment: Yep, that works just fine. It only  seems to happen inside of style="property:{{ some_variable }}"

Comment: Ok. i think i know whats going on, but first if you are using chrome, go to `inspect element` and under the tab sources look for your page and check if the style is applied there

Comment: The style is applied like I said in the main post it's applied with an invalid color, because Jinja is not expanding the variable for some reason.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. Maybe try appending the `safe` filter: `{{ product.style.color | safe }}`, or perhaps restart the server? doesn't look to be something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the bother all. I believe the problem lay in my browser not correctly loading the page, I get the problem sometimes. I opened my laptop this morning and everything worked as expected. Thank you all for contributing. Maybe it has something to do with my cookies? if someone could comment confirming that, that would be appreciated.